# Capture org-agenda and show-some-entry-text into dynamic block

Tags: org-mode

In summary I want to capture `org-agenda` into a dynamic block with some entry text.

At the end of the week I provide a report as to what I've been doing and a list of what I intend to work on in the coming week.  For listing what I have been doing I use a `clocktable` to show me time spent.  And for what's still to do, I use a custom agenda view which captures specific tags and sorts the list by priority.  For both of these tasks I have been manually copying items from the `clocktable` and agenda into my report.

So how might I create the `org-agenda` block in my report buffer automatically?

Comment: Migrated upon request by op.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part (inserting org-agenda) this is what I came up with, I wonder if there is another way?
*Using org-version 9.3.6.* (updated slightly) *for org-version 9.4.4*

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(defun org-dblock-write:sjm/org-insert-agenda (params)
  "Writes agenda items with some some text from the entry as context
to dynamic block.
Parameters are:

:key

  If key is a string of length 1, it is used as a key in
  `org-agenda-custom-commands` and triggers that command.  If it
  is a longer string it is used as a tags/todo match string.

:leaders

  String to insert before context text.  Defaults to two spaces \"  \".
  Do not use asterisk \"* \".

:count

  Maximum number of lines to include, defaults to
  org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines

:replace-what

  Regex to replace.  Defaults to heading asterisk characters and
  first uppercase word (TODO label): \"^\\* [A-Z-]* \"

:replace-with

  String to replace the org-heading star with.
  Defaults to \"- \" such that headings become list items.

Somewhat adapted from org-batch-agenda.
"
  (let ((data)
    (cmd-key (or (plist-get params :key) "b"))
    (org-agenda-entry-text-leaders (or (plist-get params :leaders) "  "))
    (org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines (or (plist-get params :count)
                        org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines))
    (replace-this (or (plist-get params :repalce-this) "^\\* [A-Z-]* "))
    (replace-with (or (plist-get params :replace-with) "- "))
    (org-agenda-sticky))
    (save-window-excursion ; Return to current  buffer and window when done.
      (if (> (length cmd-key) 1) ; If key is more than one character, THEN
      (org-tags-view nil cmd-key) ; Invoke tags view, ELSE
    (org-agenda nil cmd-key)) ; Invoke agenda view using key provided.
    (setq data (buffer-string)) ; copy agenda buffer contents to data
    (with-temp-buffer ; Using a temporary buffer to manipulate text.
      (insert data) ; place agenda data into buffer.
      (goto-char (point-max)) ; end-of-buffer
      (beginning-of-line 1)   ; beggining of last line.
      (while (not (bobp)) ; while not begging of buffer
        (when (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker) ; get text property.
          (sjm/org-agenda-entry-text)) ; Insert item context underneath.
        (beginning-of-line 0)) ; Go to previous line
      (setq data (buffer-string)))) ; Copy buffer, close tmp buf & excursion.
    ;; Paste data, replacing asterisk as per replace-this with replace-with.
    (insert (replace-regexp-in-string replace-this replace-with data))))

                    ;
(defun sjm/org-agenda-entry-text ()
  "Insert some text from the current agenda item as context.
Adapted from `org-agenda-entry-text-show-here', relies upon
`org-agenda-get-some-entry-text' for the bulk of the work."
  (save-excursion ; return to current place in buffer.
    (let (m txt o) ; declare some local variables.
    (setq m (org-get-at-bol 'org-hd-marker)) ; get text property
    (unless (marker-buffer m) ; get buffer that marker points into.
      (error "No marker points to an entry here"))
    ;; get some entry text, remove any properties and append a new-line.
    (setq txt (concat "\n" (org-no-properties
                (org-agenda-get-some-entry-text
                 m org-agenda-entry-text-maxlines
                 org-agenda-entry-text-leaders))))
    (when (string-match "\\S-" txt)
      (forward-line 1)
      (insert txt "\n\n")))))
#+end_src
```

The `org-agenda` is then applied using `C-c -C-x C-u` while within the following block

```
#+BEGIN: sjm/org-insert-agenda :key "b"
#+END:
```

I've not really looked at the first part yet.